# How to present modalViewController over all VC's in TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a UITabBarController with 5 tabs. I want to be able to present a ViewController over all of the tabs, just above the Tab Bar. Currently the issue I am having is that when I present the ViewController modally, it is not visible. I have this function called whenever I select a row within a tableView:

The tableView where `showPlayerView` is called is defined like this:

```
class SearchResultsTableView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

The class `searchResultsTableView` is a view inside of another class defined like this:

```
TestViewController: UIViewController, UserSearchDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

Here is the actual function:

```
func showPlayerView() {
    let playerView = PlayerView()
    playerView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance?.present(playerView, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}
```

and I set up the CustomTabBarController sharedInstance like this:

```
static var sharedInstance : CustomTabBarController?
```

and inside `viewDidLoad()` I have this:

```
CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance = self
```

Why can't I see my modal ViewController, and how can I get it to show on all screens?

Comment: Could you give more context about where you're running your showPlayerView method?

Comment: Just edited the question and added the class it's being run in

Comment: use a navigationcontroller maybe?

Comment: But I need it to show across all 5 VC's in my TabBarController. Would using a navBar be able to accomplish this?

Comment: show some more code and description for better understand to help you.

Comment: Is there anything specific you want me to show? I feel like everything necessary is being shown already

Answer (score 0):

```
func showPlayerView() {
    let playerView = PlayerView()
    playerView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance?.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true  // This will hide tab bar of your UITabbarViewController.
    CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance?.present(playerView, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}

// Make it visible in ViewWillApear method by below line

CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance?.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
```

Comment: That didn't work. First of all, I can't call `self.present` because self refers to the UIView. When I changed `self.present` to `CustomTabBarController.sharedInstance?.present` to try and fix this, I got this error: `Warning: Attempt to present <PlayerView: 0x7fa750911600> on <CustomTabBarController: 0x7fa74e81d600> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: I have updated my answer. try again. May this help you.

Comment: present from TestViewController will remove the warning. you can set a call back to the  TestViewController from your SearchResultsTableView

Comment: But then it won't appear on all of the 5 viewControllers in the UITabBar